# Find page IDs with specific meta tag key value pairs

Tags: custom-field

Is there a way to find the ids of the pages who contain meta tags/custom fields with a certain key-value pair?

Say, for instance, that I wanted to find all of the pages who had a meta-tag/custom-field key of "weather" with a value of "raining", is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? Same [custom field parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in query should apply and you can use `post_type` argument to limit query to pages alone.

Comment: I wasn't saying the solution could not also apply to posts, I was simply stating that the solution must apply to pages

Comment: @cmcculloh sorry, I got tone of your question as is this is something unlikely, but it seems rather simple. Unless I am missing something? Does my answer fits what you need?

Comment: ah, see, I'm a big newb, so I have no idea what is likely and what is unlikely. I'll edit my question a little. Thanks for the feedback! I'm not sure if your answer fits what I need or not, I'm still looking in to it...